Formatting cover letter
This website gives several examples of cover letters. They typically begin:
December 1, 2010

Miriam A. Nunberg
Staff Attorney
U.S. Department of Education, Office for Civil Rights
32 Old Slip, 26th Fl.
New York, NY 10005-2500

Dear Ms. Nunberg:

If you do not know the hiring manager's name and use a generic address, how would you change this format? Would you exclude the name and position and only write the company's address?

If you do not know the person responsible for your request within a company, you address your letter to the company's general mailing address and open your letter with "Dear Sir or Madam, ..." (in English).
In your case your letter might look something like this (address from this website):

Your Name
Your Address
Date
U.S. Department of Education
400 Maryland Avenue, SW
Washington, D.C. 20202
Dear Sir or Madam,
Subject of your Letter
... body text of your letter

Wikipedia gives the common format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_letter

You should try to call the firm and figure out who the hiring manager is, and what their title is.
Otherwise, your letter may be read by a secretary that discards it, or forwards it to the wrong place.
Companies seldom mind if somebody calls asking who in the company would receive an application for a particular kind of job. Most companies welcome interest from potential employees.

"I'd like to send in my resume for consideration as a warehouse worker, can you please tell me the name of the person that considers applicants for this job?"
... "And what is the department name and her title?"
... "Thank you very much."

